# MySQL user with cleared privileges can still access database

Tags: mysql

We recently made the switch from SQL Server to MySQL for new projects, and I'm still struggling to get my head around the security model.

One of our applications has a MySQL user, called MyApplicationUser. For convenience, when I was first developing this application I gave the user what I thought were the required privileges.

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER ON MyApplication.* TO 'MyApplicationUser'@'%';
```

And it seemed to work, so I thought not more about it. At some point, I adjusted this list so the user could also create indexes, although I can no longer recall the code I used to do so.

As part of a security audit, I thought it would be sensible to restrict these permissions to only those the user actually needed. So I checked what it had by running:

```
select * from information_schema.user_privileges where grantee like '%MyApplicationUser%';
```

Which have a fairly long list. Then I ran the following code:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'MyApplicationUser'@'%';   
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, EXECUTE, UPDATE ON MyApplication.* TO 'MyApplicationUser'@'%';    
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now, when I run the select from user_privileges I get only one row - USAGE. Documentation says that this is merely basic use privilege. So it looks like my GRANT command has not worked. More alarmingly, when I run the application it still seems to have the ability to read and change the data - suggesting that the account has rights other than those listed in user_privileges.

I tried restarting the MySQL service to ensure it was "fresh", but the user still had permissions to the application.

Attempting to run show grants for 'MyApplicationUser'@'%' seems to show a list of previously executed grant statements, not including my initial GRANT:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'MyApplicationUser'@'%'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, EXECUTE ON `dataportal`.* TO 'MyApplicationUser'@'%'
```

So: how can I find out what privileges my MyApplicationUser account actually has? If it really is just USAGE, how come the application still works? And how does show grants differ from user_privileges?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to make sure that your Application is no longer connected to the database server.

> Check to make sure that your application is stopped.
>   To be fairly sure, disconnect your server from the network.
>   Also, make sure you are using the root account in performing these operations.

Then, do the following steps:

- Restart MySQL Service
- Do the REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES then FLUSH
- GRANT the appropriate privileges to your user then FLUSH again
- Run `SELECT * FROM mysql.user`

Check the privileges that are marked with 'Y' then compare with the result you get from
`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USER_PRIVILEGES WHERE GRANTEE LIKE '%MYAPPLICATIONUSER%';`

As a last resort, you may have to drop the user and recreate it with appropriate privileges.

Answer (score 1):

> So: how can I find out what privileges my MyApplicationUser account actually has?

i think you can use this

```
use mysql
select * from user where user = 'username';
```